# Where does Grails 2.2 get user repository configuration?

Tags: maven, grails, gradle

Most of my company's older Grails projects have dependencies which only exist on our internal repository. The internal repository is not mentioned in any of the project configuration files (e.g. `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`). Yet my colleagues (and our Jenkins build machines) can successfully `grails test-app` directly from a git clone.

However on my own laptop, `grails test-app` says "`Failed to resolve dependencies`", and produces output indicating that no attempt has been made to fetch from the internal repo.

I can fix this by editing `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
repositories {

    mavenRepo "http://our.server:8081/maven/repo/"
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

However, it doesn't seem right that I should be hard-coding a URL into the project, when other machines don't need it.

My `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` and the contents of `$HOME/.gradle` are identical to my colleagues'. Where else can this be set?

Comment: Check out `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` for including any external config files f.e. from environment variables.

Comment: Is it possible your colleagues already have the dependencies in `$HOME/.m2/`? For example, let's say we're talking about proprietary Grails plugins. If they developed the plugins and then ran `grails install` the plugins would have been installed in `$HOME/.m2/`, as if they were downloaded from a Maven repo.